# JQuery eventhandler in external js file doen't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm not sure if im doing something wrong or if it actually doesn't work this way.

i have a jquery eventhandler like

```
$('.element').on('click',function(){
   //do something
});
```

this code comes right before my `</body>` tag. When i write the code between `<script></script>` tags it works just fine. But when i put the code in an external js file and add it with `<script src="myscript.js"></script>` at the same place, it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you put the code in a document ready handler in your external file? Eg. `$(function() { /* your code here */ })`

Comment: Please show us the code needed to repoduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is your external file is loaded in header & before DOM `.element` created. You need to place your external file link in footer, before `</body>` tag. Or wrap your code with

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('.element').on('click',function(){
           //do something
       });
   });
```

Comment: Oh damn, how could i overlook this? yes you are right and i should have known this -.- thank you